# CORS Error "PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader" for OpenSAML request to Azure AD

Tags: gwt, cors, single-sign-on, jetty, opensaml

I've searched for days now and can't find a proper solution to get my SSO via OpenSAML working. The reason for that is a CORS error "PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader" that occurs when I try to redirect the SAML request to the IdP (Azure AD).

So basically what im doing now is the following:

1. The user triggers authentication by navigating to a protected page where he is not logged in.
2. The GWT client sends a request via RPC call to the GWT server side.
3. The application, or Service Provider (SP) in SAML speak, builds a SAML authentication request (AuthnRequest) and redirects it to the IdP (Azure AD).
4. (normally the MFA would trigger but I'm getting the CORS error)

In my opinion the error is correct in this situation but how can I change the preflight header in my environment?

**System environment:**

- Java 8
- Eclipse Jetty Webserver 9.4.49
- GWT-Framework 2.8.2
- OpenSAML 3.2.0
- Azure AD as IdP

**Response Headers (Preflight):**

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 40803
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 05 Apr 2023 07:07:32 GMT
Expires: -1
Link: <https://aadcdn.msauth.net>; rel=preconnect; crossorigin
Link: <https://aadcdn.msauth.net>; rel=dns-prefetch
Link: <https://aadcdn.msftauth.net>; rel=dns-prefetch
nel: {"report_to":"network-errors","max_age":86400,"success_fraction":0.001,"failure_fraction":1.0}
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
Pragma: no-cache
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
report-to: {"group":"network-errors","max_age":86400,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://identity.nel.measure.office.net/api/report?catId=<<CAT_ID>>"}]}
Set-Cookie: fpc=AjRI9MA0hDRJhucHRbH9GwE; expires=Fri, 05-May-2023 07:07:32 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: esctx=<<COOKIE>>; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=estsfd; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: on
x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.14939.4 - WEULR2 ProdSlices
x-ms-request-id: <<REQUEST_ID>>
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

So far I've tried:

- manually setting the headers in the HttpServletResponse object of the HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder
- adding a filter to org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.ExtendedHttpService which adds the header to the HttpServletResponse
- Customizing the Jetty with a CorsHandler which extends the org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler

Comment: "Eclipse Jetty Webserver 4.9.49" does not exist.

Comment: Note that [Jetty 9.x is now at End of Community Support](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958), you should be using Jetty 10/11 or even Jetty 12 at this point in time.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt sorry its 9.4.49